# Github action: Stuck on "Start deployment (Y/n)?" - SAPUI5

Tags: github-actions, cicd

We are trying to deploy a SAPUI5 application via github actions. Right now we call the deploy command via `npm run deploy` in the github action. The step wont proceed since it is asking the user to confirm the deployment.

```
Start deployment (Y/n)?
```

However, the third party script responsible for the deployment has no option to always default to "Y".
Is there a way to let github actions enter a "Y" in such cases? Do you have another idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: All the commands used on a Github Runner are executed the same way it would be on the shell / terminal on your computer (without manual interaction). If you find a way to make the script to use `Y` by default automatically, it will also work with Github Actions. Your issue isn't with Github Actions here, it's just that the current way you perform the deploy isn't compatible with a Github Runner as it needs manual interaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```sh
yes | npm run deploy
```

This will automatically choose `y` when deploying.

Comment: Thank you!
This didn't solve my problem immediately since we are using a Windows Runner... However this inspired me to try `ECHO 'Y' | npm run deploy` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing the same kind of thing with Django. I tried this and it worked.

```bash
echo 'yes' | python manage.py collectstatic
```

The prompt was like mentioned below:

[image: Image of terminal prompt]

```
You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings:

    /home/path-to-staticfiles/

This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?

Type 'yes' to continue or 'no' to cancel:
```

I was running the command from my `github-actions`. The 'yes' is automatically picked for the prompt.

Comment: This is not necessary. Just use: `python manage.py collectstatic --noinput`. See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#cmdoption-collectstatic-noinput)